# How to escape a ! in set line of .bat file

Tags: batch-file, set, escaping

I have a password with a `!` in it.  No matter what I've tried it drops off the `!`.  My script is using `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, so I'm not sure if this is why I'm having the issue.  Here is my code:

```
set password=cccvvv!
echo %password%
```

When I run the script I get `cccvvv`.

I've tried the following:

```
set password=cccvvv!!
set password=cccvvv^^!
```

Nothing seems to work.

How can I get it to hold on to the `!` in the variable?

Comment: Have you tried putting your password in quotes? `set password="cccvvv!" echo %password%`

Answer (score 1):

Test it

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Escaped exclamation
    set "password=this is a test^!"

    rem See the environment block
    set password

    rem Echo with normal expansion
    echo %password%

    rem Echo with delayed expansion
    echo !password!
```

You need to escape the exclamation to store it inside the variable while delayed expansion is active, and the parser will usually remove it when you use the variable without delayed expansion syntax while delayed expansion is active.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to you this solution, wrapped with PowerShell ;)

```
@echo off
Title Mask/hide password entry *****
Mode con cols=60 lines=5 
:CheckPassword
cls & color 0B & echo.
set MyPassword=cccvvv!
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter your password ' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
if %MyPassword%==%password% (Goto:Good) else (Goto:Bad)
exit/b

::***********************************************************************************************
:Good
Cls & Color 0A
echo(
echo                      Good Password
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
Exit
::***********************************************************************************************
:Bad
Cls & Color 0C
echo(
echo                       Bad password
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
Goto:CheckPassword
::***********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a ^ symbol infront of the ! mark when setting the password. It will work I have checked just now before writing this answer. I also created a test.bat file just to test it
Code:

```
@echo off
set password=cccvvv!
echo %password%
pause
```

Exact Output:

```
cccvvv!
Press any key to continue . . .
```